# How to make BorderLayout dynamic?

Tags: java, swing

I have java swing aplication where I use Borderlayout as layout. I put elements in EAST,CENTER and WEST. I want to change size of elements with mouse just like in NetBeans.
For example when I move mouse on the edge of the CENTER  I need to show mouse resize cursor. And when I drag mouse on the edge, the CENTER will change size accordingly.
What is the best approach to do it?

Comment: *"What is the best approach to do it?"*  The best approach is to set the sizes of components according to their natural sizes and **not** emulate Netbeans.  But for user resizable panes, look to [`JSplitPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSplitPane.html).

Comment: Setting  size of components is obvious solution. Then another question how determine if the mouse on the edge of CENTER element ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use a [JSplitPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/splitpane.html). Simply nest them in the border layout. [This is a good resource for examples](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/JSplitPane.htm).